# How to read level plans for Javascript game?

Tags: javascript, function, html5-canvas, decode

I know there's a way to do this, I just don't remember how. I've looked through all my old javascript projects, and I can't find it anywhere. Here's what I need: I have a variable (shown below) and I want to be able to have the canvas interpret it as an image.

```
let simpleLevelPlan = `
......................
..##################..
..#................#..
..#...###....###...#..
..#...###....###...#..
..#................#..
..#................#..
..###################..
......................`;
```

Basically I want this to be interpreted so that each hashtag symbol (#) is a black square and a period (.) is a white square, so that it forms an image. I've tried a lot of stuff, but the problem I'm getting is that I can't split it up into pieces that will be read by a loop. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "homework".

Comment: Sorry, the term "homework" may not apply, but please do read the answer. It gives advice on how to ask questions like this.

Comment: Okay, I'll make sure to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic (simple) approach to achieve something in the direction you want.

```js
const asciiArt = `
......................
..##################..
..#................#..
..#...###....###...#..
..#...###....###...#..
..#................#..
..#................#..
..###################.
......................`.split("\n");

const colorMap = {
  "." : "black",
  "#" : "white"
}

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 300;

for (let y=0; y<asciiArt.length; y++) {
  for (let x=0; x<asciiArt[y].length; x++) {
    let sizeX = canvas.width / asciiArt[y].length,
        sizeY = canvas.height / asciiArt.length;
    let pixelX = sizeX * x,
        pixelY = sizeY * y;
    ctx.fillStyle = colorMap[asciiArt[y][x]] || "white";
    ctx.fillRect(pixelX, pixelY, 30, 30);  
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

---

**Some explanations**:

- We're splitting the asciiArt at the new line Characters using `.split("\n")`

```
const asciiArt = `
......................
..##################..
..#................#..
..#...###....###...#..
..#...###....###...#..
..#................#..
..#................#..
..###################.
......................`.split("\n");
```

- Now we're iterating through **y** and **x** direction of the matrix

```
for (let y=0; y<asciiArt.length; y++) {
  for (let x=0; x<asciiArt[y].length; x++) {
     // ...
  }
}
```

- In the inner for-loop we're drawing rects at the correct position with the correct color

```
colorMap[asciiArt[y][x]] 
// This is the desired color ('.' --> "black", '#' --> "white")
```

Comment: This was so helpful. Thank you so much!